# Xcode 8 Autocomplete takes 1 minute to appear

Tags: swift, xcode, autocomplete

Today I updated my project to `Swift 3.0`.

The project worked smoothly with `Xcode 7.3` and the autocomplete
had no problems. After updating to `Swift 3` the autocomplete in Xcode almost disappeared (needs 1 minute).

- Autocomplete works great with new projects, only this one has the problem.
- I tried general performance solutions like removing `"+"` on `Strings` and setting arrays without appending, but with no luck.
- I tried deleting `Derived Data`, Clean project
- I have everything from the components and simulator sections
- My project uses several Pods

**EDIT**:

When I remove suggest while typing and force it with control and space, then it works most of the times. But its not working while I type (error correction too).

When I do Pod install, although every Pod is in Swift 3 now, it asks me to convert again the project. I click "OK" and it shows 999+ errors but while generating convertion it sais there is not any convertion needed and "Update" (errors are gone when I clean the project).

Thank you

Comment: There is no known solution. Xcode 8 is slow for all things related to Swift indexing, that's all. Let's hope it's fixed soon.

Comment: So every big project is missing Autocomplete ?

Comment: i believe that is true, I have been experiencing the same issue since updating xcode as well

Comment: And in your question don't you mean to say "after updating to Xcode 8" instead of saying "after updating to Swift 3"? And I have updated to Xcode 8.1 recently and it seems to be a little bit better but still not what it was in xcode 7

Comment: Well its the same thing. Yes tried 8.1 but still the same. If you remove while typing and force it , it is a bit better but its not a solution. And as it seems the issue is still there with 8.1 so I am guessing its something in my project

Comment: I know those feels... I've had it pretty much disappear me and the only thing that fixed it was cleaning the build folder and then fully building or restarting Xcode. Reducing the amounts of inferred types seems to help a bit, but they really just need to fix their indexing.

Comment: That's Swift … Live with that or use Objective-C.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same since xcode 8. guess we have to wait for a fix.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad no offense. but how is `That's Swift … Live with that or use Objective-C` in any possible meaning a useful comment?

Comment: It is useful in the way that the OP does not spent more time on finding a solution. Additionally it offers a solution outside the path the OP intended at the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with autocompletion during my project conversion from swift 2.x to swift 3: autocompletion looked partially disappeared so I follow these steps and from that moment everything around autocompletion works fine (I hope it continue..):

- **Clean the Build** (choose Product, and Clean)
- **Reset the Simulator** (choose Reset Content and Settings, and reset)
- **Remove the app from your device** used to developing
- **Delete Derived Data** (you just know this part..)

From terminal launch this command:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
```

**Close Xcode**. Now you could try to stop indexing and re-start it because it's linked to autocompletion: if you leave it disabled, autocompletion stop to work. So from terminal do:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.XCode IDEIndexDisable 1
```

Launch Xcode and if you want you can check if your autocompletion is now  disabled, so re-close Xcode and type :

```
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEIndexDisable
```

This key remove the previous and correct index settings to default (enable), so you can try to re-open Xcode and check if autocompletion works.

My explanation for what happened to my project is that probably I've stopped accidentally indexing process (I'm impatient), so autocompletion has suffered in fact it worked partially. With this "forced re-indexing" I've solved.

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Followed every step , but again autocomplete comes after 20-30s. I am trying to do some performance changes. But I don't think thats the problem. I believe its related to the Pods installed

Comment: Interesting point, so seems to be related only to pods. Could you make the same project without pods? Let me know..

Answer (score 0):

Yes i am also getting problem with converting my old swift 2.3 project to swift 3. And I have return back to swift 2.3 because there are lots of library which are still using swift 2.3 and the xcode is try to convert the whole library code and i also got too much error. So i recommended you to use swift 2.3 in your existing app. You can try swift 3 for new apps.

Comment: In fact all my libraries are in Swift 3. I am thinking that Xcode thinks there are 2.3 libraries...

Comment: I got problem in old code and i rewrite in swift 3 step by step it work fine for me.